# How to transfer ActiveRecord::Relation values to mailer job?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, jobs

How to transfer ActiveRecord::Relation values to mailer job?

If I try to send  `cards_to_send` and get and error:

```
ActiveJob::SerializationError: Unsupported argument type: ActiveRecord::Relation
```

My `email_tasks`:

```rb
  cards = Card.where(start_date: Date.today)
  users = User.where(receive_emails: true)
  users.find_each do |user|
    cards_to_send = cards.where(user_id: user)
    TaskMailer.with(user: users, cards: cards_to_send).daily_letters.deliver_later if cards_to_send.any?
  end
```

My `task_mailer.rb`:

```rb
class TaskMailer < ApplicationMailer
  before_action { @cards, @user = params[:cards], params[:user] }
  
  def daily_letters
    mail(to: @user.email, subject: "Work plan for today.")
  end
end
```

I can convert `cards_to_send` to array `cards_to_send.to_a`, but then I can't use this array inside mailer, I get the error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `email' for #<Array:0x00007f51d83b28c0>
```

What is the correct way to send type ActiveRecord::Relation to mailer?

Comment: You're doing `users.find_each do |user|` so wouldn't you use `user` rather than `users` in the `daily_letters` call? So `TaskMailer.with(user: user ...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Just change

```rb
TaskMailer.with(user: users, cards: cards_to_send).daily_letters.deliver_later if cards_to_send.any?
```

to

```
TaskMailer.with(user: user, cards: cards_to_send.to_a).daily_letters.deliver_later if cards_to_send.any?
```

Thanks to [mu is too short](https://stackoverflow.com/users/479863/mu-is-too-short)